# Product Collection Factory not returning products that are Not Visible Individually

Tags: magento2, product-collection

Using the below code or equivelant I want to get all products regardless of visiblity or status etc. This however does not seem to return products that are "Not Visible Individually".

```
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($catid);
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code :

My Advice is please don't use objectManager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $current_category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');

$categoryId = NULL;
if($current_category) {
    $categoryId = $current_category->getEntityId();
}

    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($collection->getData());

return $collection;
```

Comment: did u get the result?

Comment: Just tried it however didn't seem to work again i did try something like that earlier and same thing happened.

Comment: Ill just double check everyhing

Comment: Even filtering to: $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE); shows no products when i can clearly see about 90 products not visible in my category  it is strange.